# Hide my div using <a href="#nice">

Tags: css, html, visibility

I'm working on a project where I need to hide a div when the a x is clicked. I'm wanting to target a specific div to be closed, the div that is holding the href nice. I'm getting a bit stuck with targeting the div once the X is clicked. Could you give any pointers for simple designer?

HTML

Div name = footer and the link class is "linky"

CSS

```
     .linky:link {
      footer:display: none;
      }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Regards,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put the link target directly before the footer:

```
<body>
    <a href="#linky">hide footer</a>
    ... other content ...
    <div id="linky"></div>
    <footer>footer</footer>
</body>
```

the use the `+` operator:

```css
#linky:target + footer {
    display: none;
}

/* to prevent scrolling to the bottom */
#linky {
    position: fixed;    
    top: 0;
}
```

[see this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/868MY/)

`a + b` will target `b` if it is directly after `a`.

Note the two additional differences from your version:

- Use `:target` instead of `:link` (`:link` will target links)
- Use `id` instead of `class`

I'd like to add that the footer will be visible again as soon as the user clicks on any other `#anchor` link.

*Update:* Now preventing scrolling; removed simple version because scrolling can not be prevented there

Comment: Hello, thanks for the tut. It took me a bit to notice on your fiddle that the text vanished on the bottom. I have to confess that I have now gone about this project differently, but thank you your help and will come back later.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<div id="div1">
    Hello, i will be hidden on click  the below link
</div>

<a href="" id="link" onClick="hide()"><b>Click here</b></a> to hide
## this is the link code
<a href="" id="link" onClick="hide()"><b>Click here</b> to hide
<script>
    function hide(){
        document.getElementById('div1').style.display="none";
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Hello thanks the help. Is that javascript? I tried it, but nothing happened... I don't see why it shouldn't work either.